# Solving particular first order pde using Lagrange's method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've got to find general solution for this pde:
$$(u^2-2yu-y^2)u_{x}+(xy+xu)u_{y}=xy-xu$$

Since $$x(u^2-2yu-y^2)+y(xy+xu)+u(xy-xu)=0$$
we can choose $\lambda=x$, $\mu=y$ and $\nu=u$. Hence, $\varphi_{x}=x$, $\varphi_{y}=y$ and $\varphi_{u}=u$, which yields $$\varphi(x,y,u)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{u^2}{2}$$

My goal now is to discover other function $\psi(x,y,u)$. I've tried a lot to find other $\lambda$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ but it haven't worked yet. So my question would be: is it possible to work out $$\frac{dy}{y+u}=\frac{du}{y-u}$$ (which is in fact $\frac{dy}{xy+xu}=\frac{du}{xy-xu}$ when multiplying both sides by $x$)? I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(u^2-2yu-y^2)u_{x}+(xy+xu)u_{y}=xy-xu$$
$$\frac{dx}{u^2-2yu-y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy+xu}=\frac{du}{xy-xu}$$
$\frac{dy}{xy+xu}=\frac{du}{xy-xu} \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{y+u}=\frac{du}{y-u}\quad\to\quad udu+ydu+udy-ydy=udu+d(yu)-ydy=0$ 
$$u^2+2yu-y^2=c_1$$
$\frac{dx}{u^2-2yu-y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy+xu}=\frac{du}{xy-xu}=\frac{xdx+ydy+udu}{x(u^2-2yu-y^2)+y(xy+xu)+u(xy-xu)}=\frac{xdx+ydy+udu}{0}\quad\implies\quad xdx+ydy+udu=0\quad\to\quad x^2+y^2+u^2=c_2$

General solution on the form of implicit equation :
$$\Phi\Big((u^2+2yu-y^2) \:,\: (x^2+y^2+u^2) \Big)=0$$

Or many other equivalent forms (implicit), such as for example :
$$u^2+2yu-y^2=F(x^2+y^2+u^2)$$

Or $\quad u=\frac{1}{2y}\Big(x^2+2y^2+G(x^2+y^2+u^2) \Big)\quad$ etc.

In the above formulas, $\Phi$, $F$ , $G$ are arbitrary functions ( related one to the others).

Comment: Could you explain how you get the fourth equality on the fifth line?

Comment: This is the application of the well known relationship between fractions :
$$\frac{x}{X}=\frac{y}{Y}=\frac{c_1x+c_2y}{c_1X+c_2Y}$$ 
and more general :
$$\frac{x_1}{X_1}=\frac{x_2}{X_2}=...=\frac{x_k}{X_k}=...=\frac{x_n}{X_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n c_kx_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n c_kX_k}$$

Comment: I was referring to the equality after that actually, where you wrote 0 for the denominator.

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now...